# which python script run to calculate mean of two variables

Tags: python

Which of the following Python scripts calculates the mean of two variables, “Exam1” and “Exam2”, from a CSV file called “ExamScores”?

Question 4 options:

```
import pandas as pd
scores = pd.read_csv('ExamScores.csv')
print(scores{'Exam1', 'Exam2'}.mean())


import pandas as pd
scores = pd.read_csv('ExamScores.csv')
print(scores[['Exam1', 'Exam2']].mean())


import pandas as pd
scores = pd.read_csv('ExamScores.csv')
print(scores[['Exam1', 'Exam2']].median())


import pandas as pd
scores = pd.read_csv('ExamScores.csv')
print(mean[['Exam1', 'Exam2']])
```

Comment: See [how to ask a homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: The answer is B

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to ask this question is mean of two columns not two variables.

You can use this code to find mean of two columns of a dataset using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
scores = pd.read_csv('ExamScores.csv')
print(scores[['Exam1', 'Exam2']].mean())
```

Thanks !